# In a Dart console application, is there a library for an HTTP Request that doesnt require DOM access?

Tags: http, console-application, httprequest, dart

I started off by trying to use HTTPRequest in `dart:html` but quickly realised that this is not possible in a console application. I have done some Google searching but can't find what I am after (only finding HTTP Server), is there a method of sending a normal HTTP request via a console application?

Or would I have to go the method of using the sockets and implement my own HTTP request?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's an [HttpClient](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/HttpClient.html) class in the IO library for making HTTP requests:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client.getUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.dartlang.org/"))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
        return request.close();
      })
    .then(HttpBodyHandler.processResponse)
    .then((HttpClientResponseBody body) {
        print(body.body);
      });
}
```

**Update:** Since HttpClient is fairly low-level and a bit clunky for something simple like this, the core Dart team has also made a [`pub`](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch04-tools-pub.html) package, [`http`](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http), which simplifies things:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  http.get('http://pub.dartlang.org/').then((response) {
    print(response.body);
  });
}
```

I found that the `crypto` package was a dependency, so my `pubspec.yaml` looks like this:

```yaml
name: app-name
dependencies:
  http: any
  crypto: any
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll be looking for the [HttpClient](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/HttpClient.html) which is part of the server side `dart:io` SDK library.

Example taken from the API doc linked to above:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/"))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
      // Prepare the request then call close on it to send it.
      return request.close();
    })
    .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
      // Process the response.
    });
```

Comment: Thank you must have missed that, I guess I should probably pay closer attention to the documentation! Sorry, marked Darshans comment as answer because he was a few seconds earlier.

Comment: I noticed that we both gave the same answer within seconds of eachother :)

Comment: Not wanting to create another question but Im having a little issue. According to the docs it says there is a setter/getter `userAgent`. However whenever I try `client.userAgent = 'Test';` Dart tells me that it has no setter/getter by that name. Am I reading the documentation wrong or is that supposed to work?