# Difference between http and HttpClient in Dart

Tags: http, dart, dart-http

I'm trying to understand the difference between the [http package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http) and the [HttpClient class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html) in the dart:io library. My purpose is to known when I should use which. I see both of them used to apparently do the same thing.

I've seen these Q&As:

- [Choosing between package:html, dart:html, dart:io (class HttpClient) and package:http APIs to fetch HTTP resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30278442/choosing-between-packagehtml-darthtml-dartio-class-httpclient-and-package)
- [How to make HTTPS request using HttpClient in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703406/how-to-make-https-request-using-httpclient-in-dart)
- [In a Dart console application, is there a library for an HTTP Request that doesnt require DOM access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197983/in-a-dart-console-application-is-there-a-library-for-an-http-request-that-doesn)
- [How to do POST in Dart command line HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491543/how-to-do-post-in-dart-command-line-httpclient)

This is what I think is true so far but my understanding is fuzzy:

- `http` is high level and `HttpClient` is low level ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17198402/3681880))
- <s>`http` can make post requests but `HttpClient` can't ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491543/how-to-do-post-in-dart-command-line-httpclient))</s>
- both `http` and `HttpClient` (with `HttpClientRequest`) can make GET and POST requests ([source](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html))
- both `http` and `HttpClient` can be used on the client and the server

So to sum it up, I would say that each one can do anything that the other can as well, but it is easier to use the `http` package since this one is more *high-level*. Is that summary correct?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `http` package is an abstraction over `dart:io` and `dart:html`.

So if you want to share code between browser and other platforms that makes HTTP requests, then it's best to use the `http` package. Then the code will just work everywhere.

If you don't care about the browser use what API you like best. In Flutter the `http` package just wraps `dart:io`'s `HttpClient`.